# pushing public package to azure devops feed

Tags: azure-devops

In artifacts I have created a feed,and all seems good. It publishes my packages to the feed.Good

If I understood it correctly it can work like a " private Nuget server" if you like and have all the packages that your team should be using.

I need to push several public packages to my feed.

EG How can I push  "Newtonsoft" version 11.2 to my feed on azure devops?

Is this a manual step? 
Can be automated?

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do anything. Configure your feed to use NuGet.org as an [upstream package source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/upstream-sources?view=vsts) and any packages that are available on NuGet will be automatically cached when restored.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply.When i look at upstream sources . Nuget.org was already there. I was expecting a way to upload only certain nugets so that I could control their versions. EG like a private nuget.. Does it make sense .Am I missing the obvious?